# Sprite not drawing at correct position

Tags: sprites

I have a texture with 20x20 pixels.

Consider this piece of code:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture,Position * 20,null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2),1, SpriteEffects.None,1);
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Position=(0,0)

[image]

But when I use `new Vector2(10,10)` in the following code

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture,Position * 20+new Vector2(10,10),null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2),1, SpriteEffects.None,1);
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

It draws at the correct position. How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what makes that position correct. Are you trying to position the texture different from where it is drawn, which starts at the upper left?

Answer (score 0):

The line we're interested in is

```
Position * 20
```

which, if Position is (0,0), is equal to (0,0)

and you say it behaves correctly for

```
Position * 20 + new Vector2(10,10)
```

which is equal to (10,10)

I'm guessing that the problem is a misunderstanding of order of operation. Adding parenthesis to show what happens first, we would have:

```
(Position * 20) + new Vector2(10,10)
```

Comment: <pre> public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(0,0), null, Color.White,0f,new Vector2(texture.Width/2,texture.Height/2), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }<code>
so I edited it and the same, lack of 10pixel

Answer (score 0):

This is a debugging issue. The image gets drawn where you are telling it to be drawn. The problem is you are not telling it to draw in the correct place. Use the debugger to examine `Position` when you enter the `Draw()` method. My guess is that `Position` will not have the value that you are expecting.  If this is the case, look through your code, and find where `Position` is being set, or where it is being changed, and make sure those bits of code are doing what they are suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're *asking*, but based on everything you *stated* I don't see any issues.

Position is `(0, 0)`, the texture dimensions are `20 x 20` and the origin which you specified in the `Draw` method is `new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2)`.

What I see in the screenshot appears to be correct, with the top left corner of the texture being at `(0, 0)` after specifying its origin to be `(10, 10)` and moving it by `(10, 10)`.